# can I get text from html and put it into variable in php without submitting a form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a form in html:

```
<form>
<label><input type="hidden" name="pNameChange" value=""></label>
</form>
```

and I want to get the value of this input in php without submitting it in a form.

this is my javascript:

```
var pName= null;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').click(function(){
        pName= $(this).attr("name");
        console.log(pName);
    });
});
```

My php:

```
$pName = isset($_POST['pNameChange']) ? $_POST['value'] : '';
```

what I want is. you click on the picture,

1.the value of the name attribute of the picture is going to be saved into the variable `pName` (javascript),

2.it then goes into the form and changes the value of the form to the variable `pName` (javascript),

3.php picks up the value of the form (which should now be equal to `pName`),

4.then stores it into a variable `$pName` (php).

5.I also want `$pName` (php) to be globally used throughout all the pages of the website.

*edit*

this is my index page:

```
<?php
$pName = isset($_POST['pNameChange']) ? $_POST['value'] : '';
$db_connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','',"project_online_planner");
if (!$db_connection){
    die('Failed to connect to MySql:'.mysql_error());
}
$query="SELECT * FROM project limit 5 ";
$results = mysqli_query($db_connection,$query);
$intro=mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Project planner online</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ppo.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ppo.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="bgNav">
    <div id="login">
        <a href="register.php">Register</a>
        <a href="login.php">Log in</a>
    </div>

    <nav id="nav">
        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
    </nav>
</div>
<h2 class="titlePage">Home</h2>
<div id="bgTile">
    <?php

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
    {
        $project = $row["name"];
        echo nl2br("<a href='project.php'>" ."<img name=\"$project\" width='100px' alt='Procject name' height='100px' class='tile' src=". $row['image'] ."/>". "</a>");
    }
    ?>

    <a href="allprojects.php"><div class="tile" id="tileM"><h2>Meer</h2></div></a>

</div>
    <form>
        <label><input type="hidden" name="pNameChange" value=""></label>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

what I want: click on the image then you get sent to the project page where (php) `$pName` is equal to the value of (javascript) `pName`

project page:

```
<?php
$newRecord = null;
$pName = isset($_POST['pNameChange']) ? $_POST['value'] : '';
$db_connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','',"project_online_planner");
if (!$db_connection){
    die('Failed to connect to MySql:'.mysql_error());
}

//insert into database
if(isset($_POST['insertComments'])){
    include('connect-mysql.php');
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO user_comments (username, comment, project) VALUES ('$username', '$comment', '$pName')";
        if (!mysqli_query($db_connection, $sqlinsert)){
            die('error inserting new record');
        }
        else{
            $newRecord = "1 record added";
        }//end nested statement

}

//text from database
$query="SELECT * FROM user_comments where project = '$pName' ";
$results = mysqli_query($db_connection,$query);
$intro=mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);

$query2="SELECT * FROM project where name = '$pName' ";
$results2 = mysqli_query($db_connection,$query2);
$intro2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($results2);


?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Project planner online</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ppo.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ppo.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="intro">

</div>
<div id="bgNav">
    <nav id="nav">
        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
        <a class="rightNav" href="register.php">Register</a>
        <a class="rightNav" href="login.php">Log in</a>
    </nav>
</div>

<div id="projectTile">
    <span id="statusCheck"><?php print_r($intro2["status"]); ?></span>
    <h2 id="prTitle"><?php print_r($intro2["name"]); ?></h2>
<div id="prPic"><img width="300" height="200" src="<?php print_r($intro2["image"]); ?>"></div>
<div id="prDescription"><?php print_r($intro2["description"]); ?></div>
</div>
<div id="comments">
    <?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
    {
        echo nl2br("<div class='profile_comments'>" . $row['username'] . "</div>");
        echo nl2br("<div class='comment_comments'>" . $row['comment'] . "</div>");
    }
    ?>

</div>

<div id="uploadComments">
    <form method="post" action="project.php">
        <label for="name"><input type="hidden" name="insertComments" value="true"></label>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>comment</legend>
        <label>Name:<input type="text" id="name" name="username" value=""></label><br/>
        <label>Comments: <textarea name="comment" id="comment"></textarea></label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitComment">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
<?php
echo $newRecord;
?>
<form>
    <label><input type="hidden" name="pNameChange" value=""></label>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you know about ajax?

Comment: No, I don't. I have no experience with it at all.

Comment: please post the html code where you have an image with the name attribute.

Comment: edited with more details

Comment: Let me get this right: when you click on the image in `index.php`, you should then navigate to `project.php` and also the clicked image's `name` should be passed to the `$pName` variable in `project.php`?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML:

do you have more then 1 image on page? its better if you add ID in image. No need for form and hidden fields for what you want done.

make sure your img has ID like `<img id="imageID"...`

JavaScript:

```
var pName= null;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#imageID').click(function(){
        pName= $(this).attr("name");
        $.post("project.php", { pNameChange: pName },
        function(data) {
            // do something here.
         });
    });
});
```

---

above code should work as expected. Now in project.php > $_POST['pNameChange'] should receive the value of pName (image's name attr).

I don't understand what you want when you said $pName available globally on all pages. Please elaborate further, may be look into storing it as cookie/session?

---

EDIT:

Consider using session to pName value... by simple starting/resuming session in start of file:

```
<?PHP
  session_start();
```

and then...

to set/update value:

```
if(isset($_POST["pNameChange"]))
$_SESSION["pName"] = $_POST["pNameChange"];
```

and then use `$_SESSION["pName"]` instead of `$pName` on all pages.

Comment: I've tried it this way, but it's still not working. When I print pName to the console it give me a value of null.

Comment: updating my answer... you dont need form for it

Comment: Sorry, it does work, but when the page refreshes (goes to another page) the value goes back to null and the variable $pName in php doesn't change. it does print the correct name to the console though.

Comment: consider using sessions

Answer (score 0):

Try Ajax method in jQuery , hope it solves your problem

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

or

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you do not need AJAX for this, all your `index.php` does it passes the image's `name` to `project.php` so try:

In `index.php`:

```
<form name='form1' method="post" action='project.php'> <!-- form attributes given -->
        <label><input type="hidden" name="pNameChange" value=""></label>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var pName= null;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').click(function(){
        //onclick of image, we will save the image name into the hidden input
        //and submit the form so that it goes to project.php
        $('input[name="pNameChange"]').val($(this).attr("name")); 
        $('form1').submit()
    });
});
```

And in your `project.php`:

```
//now project.php can get the posted value of 'pNameChange'
//There is no input field with `name`->`value`, so $_POST['value'] is invalid.
$pName = isset($_POST['pNameChange']) ? $_POST['pNameChange'] : '';
```

And if you need this value across multiple pages, global will not work, use sessions.

Answer (score 0):

ok this "additional" answer is to focus on session only. use the codes for client-end from my previous answer and try this on server-end.

index.php Page:

```
<?php
session_start();
$pName = isset($_SESSION['pNameChange']) ? $_SESSION['pNameChange'] : '';
```

project.php Page:

```
<?php
session_start();
$newRecord = null;
$pName = isset($_SESSION['pNameChange']) ? $_SESSION['pNameChange'] : null;
if(is_null($pName) && isset($_POST['pNameChange'])) {
   $_SESSION['pNameChange'] = $_POST['pNameChange'];
   $pName = $_POST['pNameChange'];
}
```

hope it helps